# Couldn't get the correct height of the wkWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiscrollview, contentsize

I have read lots of articles about how to get height of the webView. Most of them use KVO to observe the contentSize. I also did that.

1) create wkWebView and forbid webView's scrollView

```
 lazy var webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()

 webView.scrollView.bounces = false
 webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

 webView.snp.makeConstraints({ (make) in
        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp.bottom)
        make.height.equalTo(AppDefaults.screenH - 64 - 44)
        make.bottom.equalTo(containView)
    })
```

2) add observer

```
webView.scrollView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "contentSize" {
        if let scroll = object as? UIScrollView {
            if scroll.contentSize.height > 0 {
                updateWebViewConstraints(scroll.contentSize.height)
            }
        }
    }
}

func updateWebViewConstraints(_ height: CGFloat) {
    webView.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp.bottom)
        make.height.equalTo(height)
        make.bottom.equalTo(containView).offset(-44)
    }
}
```

3) remove observer

```
deinit {
    webView.scrollView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}
```

When I run the app, sometimes I can get the correct height of the webView which was show right. Like below images

[image]

[image]

But sometimes ,the height of the webView over the correct height , it cause webView have part of empty space. We can see the below images, it get the wrong contentSize,

[image]
[image]

And when I tap the nextButton to load the new content, it also keep the previous height. That's not good. Just like if the contentSize's height over the new content's height. It will not change.

In order to compare wkWebView, so I have tried UIWebView, it was correct. So, I don't know how to solve that problem. Please give me some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the `contentSize` of the page you're rendering is less than the `bounds` of the `WKWebView`, the `contentSize` will be at least the same as the `bounds`, which results in a blank space.

The only way you could get around this was to set the `bounds` of your `WKWebView` to something less than the size of the content. Once the page renders you will know the size of the `WKWebView.scrollView`'s `contentSize` and you can size it using your logic above.

Comment: Thanks first.  If the contentSize of the page I'm rendering is less than the bounds of the WKWebView, the contentSize will be at least the same as the bounds. I know it. You said that is the right way. For me, the second condition is the height of the contentSize over the correct contentSize. It means when the height of the contentSize over screenHeight. It will cause that problem. I also set webView constraint before.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.webViewHeightConstraint?.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        self.webViewHeightConstraint?.constant = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

I faced the same issue. Based on runmad's solution, setting the height to zero before load and setting the correct height afterward works.